# YouTube embeds should be full-screenable

Tags: feature-request

I hate not being able to full screen the YouTube videos embedded on Stack Exchange sites.

What's the reason for blocking full screen?

Please enable it...

Comment: Do you get an error message "full screen is unavailable", or does the button simply not work? If the site actually blocks full screen video, you'll get an error message when clicking the button.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousWizHog the button is greyed-out, and clicking it shows that message